# Is a Pythagorean triple uniquely determined by its smallest element?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

A triple $(a,b,c)$ is a Pythagorean triple if $a,b$ and $c$ are strictly positive integers satisfying $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

Do there exist $a,b,c,b',c'$ for which $(a,b,c)$ and $(a,b',c')$ are both Pythagorean triples, with $a \le b$ and $a\le b'$, but $b\neq b'$?

[Such examples do exist as commenters below have pointed out.]

Comment: (105,208,233) and (105,608,617) are a pair of primitive Pythagorean triples with the same shortest element. If you allow non-primitive ones there are smaller examples.

Comment: Another primitive pair is 385, 552, 673 and 385, 1488, 1547.  When you have a leg with three different prime factors you get nonunique primitive triples.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.

Comment: (20,21,29) and (20,99,101) is a smaller primitive pair, where the shared shortest side is even.

Comment: There are primitive examples with the smallest having length $84.$ Specifically, $84,437,445$ and $84,187,205$ and $84,1763,1765.$

Comment: More generally, if $b>1$ and $a>b(\sqrt 2+1)$ then there are triples $2ab,a^2-b^2,a^2+b^2$ and $2ab,a^2b^2-1,a^2b^2+1.$ These are primitive if $a,b$ are relatively prime and not both odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an infinite class of primitive Pythagorean pairs.

Give integers $a,b$ with $b>1,$

1. $a>(\sqrt 2+1)b,$ and
2. $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and
3. $a,b$ are not both odd.

Then we have triples:

$$(2ab,a^2-b^2,a^2+b^2)\\
(2ab,a^2b^2-1,a^2b^2+1)$$

Condition $1.$ ensures $a^2-b^2>2ab.$ Conditions $2.$ and $3.$ ensure the triples are primitive.

---

The smallest pair is $(a,b)=(5,2)$ which gives the triples listed in comments:

$$(20,21,29)\\(20,99,101)$$